# SQL group by with Case statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table that looks something like this

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Report_id |  Status   |        Date         |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 | Completed | 2020-06-07 12:20:00 |
|         1 | Completed | 2020-06-07 12:22:00 |
|         2 | Running   | 2020-06-07 13:02:00 |
|         2 | Completed | 2020-06-07 13:10:00 |
|         3 | Completed | 2020-06-07 14:10:00 |
|         3 | Failed    | 2020-06-07 14:04:00 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I need to group this data by *Report_id*. So if all status values within groups are equal to Completed than *Status* is Completed and *Date* is the max value within group. But if there is one Running or Failed value within group than *Status* needs to be equal to Running and Failed respectively and *Date* should match this value.

The output will look like this.

```
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
| Report_id |  Status   |        Date         |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
|         1 | Completed | 2020-06-07 12:22:00 |
|         2 | Running   | 2020-06-07 13:02:00 |
|         3 | Failed    | 2020-06-07 14:04:00 |
+-----------+-----------+---------------------+
```

I suspect I need to use Case statement somewhere to get this output but I can't figure out how. Please help.

Comment: Can you show us what have you tried so far ? Also please can you tag your database ?

Comment: @VBoka I haven't succeeded in anything yet. I'm using postgresql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use STRING_AGG to combine the text of the status columns into one string and check if that string contains 'running' or 'failed'

```
select report_id, 
case when STRING_AGG(status, '') like '%Running%' then 'Running'
when STRING_AGG(status, '') like '%Failed%' then 'Failed'
else 'Completed' end Status,
max(date) Date
from abc
group by report_id
```

Comment: Thank you! I find your solution the shortest and most suitable for me

Answer (score 0):

Looking to your sample seem you need the firts status (based on date)  for each report

```
select m.* 
from my_table m
inner join (
    select Report_id,  min(date) min_date
    from my_table  
    group by Report_id
) t on t.Report_id = m. and t.min_date  = m.date
```

Comment: No, this won't work. If everything is completed than i need the last date. If status is Failed or Running than i need its date, and it can have any date, so minimum date won't work here

Comment: @DenisKudriavtsev   we are not in your db and in your mind  .. the only things we can know are in your question and data sample so .  you should explain better your needs ..  in your comment  you say "If everything is completed than i need the last date, " ..  for you report_id  = 2 this  is not coherent with you sample result

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select report_id,status,date, row_number() over(partition by report_id order by 
case when status in ('Running','Failed') then 1 else 2 end asc,Date desc) as rn
from tablename
)A where rn=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's what you are looking for,and also if this is completely running.

```
select report_id,
    case when q.failed_sum > 0 then 'Failed'
         when q.running_sum > 0 then 'Running'
        else  'Completed'
    end,
    max(date)
    from table inner join
        (
            select report_id, 
            sum(case when status = 'Failed' then 1 end) as failed_sum,
            sum(case when status = 'Running' then 1 end) as running_sum,
            sum(case when status = 'Completed' then 1 end)as completed_sum
            from table 
            group by report_id
        )q on report_id = q.report_id
    where status = (case when failed_sum > 0 then 'Failed'
        else when running_sum > 0 then 'Running'
        else then 'Completed'
    end) 
    group by report_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (record_id) t.*
from t
order by (case when status <> 'Completed' then 1 else 2 end),
         date desc;
```